# Find a duplicated value from different columns in mySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table with two text column, and I would like to find all the records that have duplicate text in this two columns. What is the best query I can use to find the duplicates?

and to understand the total number of texts in this two columns except duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by below sql query.

```
 select * from tableName where column1 == column2
```

Comment: null safe equal in mysql is <=> and op does not say test has to be on same row - so I'm surprised by the upvote